# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Updated question and below my code after adding hibernate core and changes in pom file to spring-orm

I am trying to use Spring MVC and get data from server and store it in database i am able to get data from server, i am trying to use hibernate to store data in mysql database but i am getting below error while running the code

error:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/frr1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

My pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>frr1</groupId>
  <artifactId>frr1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>frr1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>



        <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency> -->


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->

 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
  </dependency>-->


    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>frr1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

BeanLocations.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>

    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="../spring/beans/Issue.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Hibernate.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>

     <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
           <value>/hibernate/issue.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
      </property>   

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Use this pom.xml  http://pastebin.com/SPQrVXYg  , it has all the dependencies a good growing project requires and a few extra, remove one by one which you don't need. Remove, test, if error re-insert the dependency. Rinse and repeat. Dont forget to put name of project at top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: its giving below error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [resources/database/Hibernate.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: You should check your dependency for hibernate, loks like you miss hibernate-core dependency

Comment: i have made changes and getting other error even i have added     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
  </dependency>-->

Comment: getting different error after adding even  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
  </dependency>

its giving me same error after including so i commented it

the error is i have updated the question

Comment: You are constantly changing the content of your question.
You started with problem with spring, then hibernate, now with a logging.
Don't do this. Or describe your edits.
I repeat once again - you have problems with dependencies, so check them again. Take a look on simple tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration